# Silverlight -> Set Enum Value via Expression -> TypeAccessException

Tags: c#, silverlight, lambda, expression

The following Code generates my Setter Func from which I can set a enum Property of a object via a string!

```
    public static Action<TObject, TProperty> GetPropSetter<TObject, TProperty>(PropertyInfo pinfo)
    {
        ParameterExpression paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObject));

        ParameterExpression paramExpression2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProperty), pinfo.Name);

        var prop2 = Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(typeof (Enum).GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] {typeof (Type), typeof (string), typeof(bool)}), Expression.Constant(pinfo.PropertyType), paramExpression2, Expression.Constant(true)), pinfo.PropertyType);

        MemberExpression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(paramExpression, pinfo.Name);

        Action<TObject, TProperty> result = Expression.Lambda<Action<TObject, TProperty>>
            (
                Expression.Assign(propertyExpression, prop2), paramExpression, paramExpression2
            ).Compile();

        return result;
    }
```

This works perfectly in WPF! But when I run it in Silverlight I got this error:

> Fehler beim Versuch von Methode
> "DynamicClass.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,
> MCC.ConnectorsV2.WMSConnectorServiceInterfaces.DTO.TransportLabelDTO,
> System.String)", auf Typ "System.RuntimeType" zuzugreifen.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, but you do know that you can set properties with `pinfo.SetValue(myObj, myValue, null)`, do you?

Comment: Yes, but I think that uses reflection and is slower?

Comment: Yes, I see what you're getting at.